# Javascript: Regex to escape parentheses and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

Looking to backslash escape parentheses and spaces in a javascript string.

I have a string: `(some string)`, and I need it to be `\(some\ string\)`

Right now, I'm doing it like this:

```
x = '(some string)'
x.replace('(','\\(')
x.replace(')','\\)')
x.replace(' ','\\ ')
```

That works, but it's ugly. Is there a cleaner way to go about it?

Comment: Your code doesn't actually work. It will only replace the first occurrence of each character, not all of them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can do this:

```
x.replace(/(?=[() ])/g, '\\');
```

`(?=...)` is a lookahead assertion and means 'followed by'

`[() ]` is a character class.

Comment: What's the point of the lookahead here?  Why not just match `/[() ]/g`?

Comment: Ah, nevermind . . . I missed that you weren't using the capturing group in the replacement string.

Comment: @talemyn: Yes, it is for this reason. However a solution as Barmar wrote works well too.

Comment: This worked - though now there is a new wrinkle. I need to add the dash `-` to the list of escaped characters, though that seems to eliminate everything which follows the dash from the string.

Comment: @KevinWhitaker: the dash is a special character in a character class (it is used to define character ranges), you can: 1) escape it, 2) put it at the begining of the character class, 3) put it at the end of the character class.

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression, and `$0` in the replacement string to substitute what was matched in the original:

```
x = x.replace(/[() ]/g, '\\$0')
```