# JQuery selector cointains parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div's with ids that are pulled from a database. These ids sometimes contain parentheses and this causes the JQuery selector to not work. What can I do?

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

https://jsfiddle.net/2uL7s3ts/1/

```
var element = 'hello (world)';
$('#' + element).hide();
```

Comment: And there's the [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute selector for ID

```
$("[id='" + element + "']").hide();
```

or modify your string selector with a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872990/2278598) to remove the parentheses and spaces

```
element = element.replace(/(?=[() ])/g, '\\');
$('#' + element).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an attribute selector, as the other answer suggests, I would suggest switching back to the native `getElementById` method.

```
$(document.getElementById(element)).hide();
```

The reason I sugguest this over an attribute selector is for performance reasons.  An attribute can exist on any element, so when you perform it, javascript has to scan every element within the context to see if it has the attribute with a matching value.

Using `getElementById`, which takes a literal id and not a selector, the DOM scan will not happen.